# Material Design lite fonts and icons

Tags: material-design-lite

How can I use material fonts and icons locally, because I have not always access to the internet to reference it through http.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

According to their [guide](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) you can [download](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) icons as `svg` and `png`, as well as [download the icon fonts themselves](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont) and implementing them like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(myLocalFontDir/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(myLocalFontDir/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(myLocalFontDir/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(myLocalFontDir/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

The you can use them without an internet connection:

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

The icons are available for download from https://www.google.com/design/icons/

Answer (score 0):

The Material Design font for western languages is all Roboto, which are Google fonts. Those are downloadable, too, from many places.